# mysql - Getting error while calling procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am getting error while executing the below procedure.

I am casting the varchar variable to unsigned below..

Error :

```
Query : call procedureName(@examDetails) 
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'v_subTopicsIds' in 'field list'
```

Please help me i am unable to know why i am getting this error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake with name of variable.

You should replace `v_subTopicIds` with `v_subTopicsIds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a spelling mistake.Use `v_subTopicIds` instead of `v_subTopicsIds`

```
 WHERE ID = CAST(v_subTopicIds AS UNSIGNED)
```

---

```
SELECT LENGTH(v_subTopicIds) - LENGTH(REPLACE(v_subTopicIds,
```

---

```
SELECT split_string(v_subTopicIds,
```

Comment: @user3185790 can you check my answer